# Sort index alphabetically on first, second, third characters

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}, 
                  index=['13th str', '3SAT', 'ARD', 
                         'ARD Dritte', 'AXNAction', 'Animal', 'bb'])
            val
13th str      0
3SAT          0
ARD           0
ARD Dritte    1
AXNAction     0
Animal        0
bb            0
```

I would like to sort it to look like this,

```
            val
13th str      0
3SAT          0
Animal        0
ARD           0
ARD Dritte    1
AXNAction     0
bb            0
```

note - 'Animal' has shifted places.

If all the first letters are the same then look at the next character and so on.

Here is what I have tried which has not worked:

```
df.sort()
df = df.sort_index()
df = df.index.sort_values() #gives an 'Index' object has no attribute 'sort_values' error
```

Comment: did you try `df.sort_index()`?

Comment: yep, sure did but didn't change the order.

Comment: It would help if you posted your efforts, `sort_index` would've worked, if you didn't assign back the result or didn't pass `inplace=True` then it would've failed but you didn't include this in your question

Comment: I've updated the code and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Hold on, the index is sorted correctly, you're asking to sort lower case  characters before capital letters which is incorrect. If you want to change this then you need to either change the index to lower case or temporarily add a lower case column sort using that column and drop the column

Comment: so sorry! missed the "A" in animal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your index is sorted correctly as uppercase characters are sorted before lower case which is why your attempts failed, to sort the way you want you can add a temporary column with the lower case index values, sort by this column and then drop it:

```
In [155]:
df['labels'] = df.index.str.lower()
df = df.sort_values('labels').drop('labels', axis=1)
df

Out[155]:
            val
13th str      0
3SAT          0
Animal        0
ARD           0
ARD Dritte    1
AXNAction     0
bb            0
```

Comment: Thanks Ed! Much appreciated!

Comment: tried this but it says 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'?

Comment: what version pandas do you have? Also you need to post data and code that reproduces this

Comment: 0.16.2 is the version im using, is there a way to do it in this version?

Comment: This was added in [0.17.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-sorting-api) so you'd need to call `sort` instead for `0.16.2`

Comment: sort() works but now I get this error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'start'. Because its a multiindex df..

Comment: Seriously I can't debug based on comments, either post a new question or update your question with raw data, code, desired output, your attempts, and any errors

Comment: Im so sorry Ed! its working now, used this. "df.drop('labels', axis=1, level=0)", SORRY!

Comment: no problem but you have to see things from our perspective, we can only help with the info you give us, telling us the symptoms doesn't help. Glad you were able to sort this out

Comment: Totally understand Ed, I had absolutely no time hence I didnt open a new thread but I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the index [using a custom `key` function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting):

```
In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}, 
              index=['13th str', '3SAT', 'ARD', 
                     'ARD Dritte', 'AXNAction', 'Animal', 'bb'])


In [23]: df

Out[23]: 

        val

13th str      0
3SAT          0
ARD           0
ARD Dritte    1
AXNAction     0
Animal        0
bb            0


In [24]: df.index = sorted(df.index.values, key=lambda s: s.lower())


In [25]: df

Out[25]: 
        val
13th str      0
3SAT          0
Animal        0
ARD           1
ARD Dritte    0
AXNAction     0
bb            0
```

Comment: this is a neater answer than mine +1, when I looked at this I couldn't understand the problem until I noticed the uppercase letters, unclear to me if the OP realised this or not

Comment: Found a problem with this version! It doesnt retain the values associated to the labels